# EWS managed API, is there a way to view SOAP packets?

Tags: exchangewebservices

Using the EWS managed api, (`ExchangeService` and etc), how can I view the actual SOAP of requests/responses without using a proxy?

If I get an error from the api, how can I view the contents of the packet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tracing see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495632(v=exchg.150).aspx that will output the request and responses sent/receive. The other thing is if you compile you own Dll from github https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api you should be able to debug the error if its a parse issue on the receive side.